# d3js: Svg element not getting resized on changing window size

Tags: javascript, d3.js, responsive

I have a svg element and I am trying to make it responsive. The code that I am using is given below but this does not work. I don't understand the issue.

```
 var svg = d3.select('.chart')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('class', 'chart')
            .attr("width", width + margin + margin)
            .attr("height", height + margin + margin + 10   )
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 680 490")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + 
 ")");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Following worked for me. Thanks anyway :)

```
var svg = d3.select('.chart')
            .classed("svg-container", true)
            .append('svg')
            .attr('class', 'chart')
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 680 490")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

.svg-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%; /* aspect ratio */
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.svg-content-responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the width and height there. From experience, I know that an SVG with width and height set is very difficult to resize. I use the viewbox only and do sizing with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

That code will run only once and set its size to the initial window height and width values. If you want it to resize when window size is changed, you need to resize it on [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) event.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    // code to change svg element's width/height here
}
```